# Model Binding in ASP.NET Core MVC with Collection

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core-mvc

How do I use the Property from the `Project.Project_ID` Class so that it can be called in the `R_Project _Status` Class and can be displayed in View ASP.NET CORE C#?
please explain the example with MVC

**Problem**

[image]

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Can you provide sample data? I guess the solution should be in Linq?

Answer (score 0):

You should use EF with Linq:
I hope, you've successfully "scaffolded", guessing, you already have the following classes:

```
public partial class Project
{
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public int Source { get; set; }

    public virtual RSource SourceNavigation { get; set; }
}
public partial class RProjectStatus
{
    public int StatusType { get; set; }
    public int Source { get; set; }

    public virtual RSource SourceNavigation { get; set; }
}
public partial class RSource
{
    public RSource()
    {
        Project = new HashSet<Project>();
        RProjectStatus = new HashSet<RProjectStatus>();
    }

    public int Source { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Project> Project { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<RProjectStatus> RProjectStatus { get; set; }
}
```

Everything, you have to do now, is (assuming, you already have _context as DatabaseContext)

```
var ps = _context.RProjectStatus
                .Include(x => x.SourceNavigation)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.Project);
// now do any stuff you want with "ps" variable:
List<int> projectIdList = ps.FirstOrDefault()
            .SourceNavigation
            .Project
            .Select(x => x.ProjectId)
            .ToList();
```